# Pythonic alternative of gotoxy C code

Tags: python

I want to make a menu-driven program for elementary database management.

So, please provide me some idea on how to use alternative of gotoxy in python with the help of below example.

I have C code which draws a vertical & a horizontal line in the center of screen as below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define HLINE for(i=0;i<79;i++)\
                  printf("%c",196);
#define VLINE(X,Y) {\
                     gotoxy(X,Y);\
                     printf("%c",196);\
                   }
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  clrscr();
  gotoxy(1,12);
  HLINE
  for(y=1;y<25;y++)
      VLINE(39,y)
  return 0;
}
```

Is there something like `gotoxy()` in Python too?

Comment: You might want to check out http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html or http://urwid.org/

Comment: There are numerous hits when searching "gotoxy Python" online. Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's no such thing as `gotoxy` or `clrscr` in standard C. You're using a platform-specific library which provides them. The solution is the same for Python: use a library. One library that supports a vast number of terminals and is part of the Python distribution is `curses`. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html for the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I found to do this, is to write a gotoxy function:

```
def gotoxy(x,y):
    print ("%c[%d;%df" % (0x1B, y, x), end='')
```

This works quite well for `python3`. If you want to use `python2` you need the line:
`from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: There is another way for windows: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Cursor_positioning#Python

Comment: This solution depends on the terminal supporting those escape sequences. It won't work in all environments.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux and other UNIX-like systems you should use NCURSES libraty. See [python ncurses howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html).

On Windows, there is no ncurses. You can use [Console](http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm) module.

Consider alternatives. It will be much simpler to use existing GUI library. Here is the [list of crosspatform python UI libs](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/gui.html).

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/npyscreen

Try link above, it wonderfully integrates style of coding of "big" GUI libs (like GTK, Qt, Tkinter, etc) aith ncurses representation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-gotoxy-function-used-in-c)
I tried :
 with x = 4, y = 3
`print "%c[%d;%df" % (0x1B, x, y),`

and it works
thanks Rutrus

Comment: Where x=4 and y=3. In python3 you can write `print ("%c[%d;%df" % (0x1B, y, x), end='')`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system, it might be worth considering the wconio library. I mention it here anyway as another option for the benefit of anyone doing a search.

As mentioned elsewhere, Borland Pascal's gotoxy() and relatives went to Turbo C's conio.h and then to other Cs, they are not part of the C language.

wconio is a partial port of the conio module to Python, see

http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/wconio.html

Also https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=wconio

Answer (score 0):

I find the following code from https://www.programmersought.com/article/64334507936/ and I completed it with adding gotoxy() function.

You should first import **ctypes** module:

```
import ctypes

class COORD(ctypes.Structure):
   _fields_ = [("X", ctypes.c_short), ("Y", ctypes.c_short)] 

   def __init__(self,x,y):
       self.X = x
       self.Y = y

def gotoxy(x,y):
    INIT_POS=COORD(y,x)
    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE= -11
    hOut = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut,INIT_POS)
```

you should just Initialize gotoxy(x,y) with x and y.
for example:

```
gotoxy(12,5)
```